# Can anyone translate this old headstone from Germany?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, inscription

This is the text that I can see. Hopefully you will be able to view the image if I can add it.

I've tried various translation sites but nothing is really working. I could makes guesses but I'm very curious exactly what it says and means.  V's could be U's and this headstone is located in Memmingen, Stadtkreis Memmingen, Bavaria (Bayern), Germany.

> MORTALITI SVA MEMOR
>   REIP MEMMING SENATI
>   ET
>   PHARMACOP
>   BIPONT NAT
>   MDCCVI DIE XXIV APRS (April 24 1706?)
>   MONVMENT HOC SEPVLCRALE
>   PARAVIT
>   SIBI POSTERISQVE SVIS
>   MDCCLXXII (1772?)

[Here](http://images.findagrave.com/photos/2015/345/UNCEM_1449859976765.jpg) is a link to the image.

Answer (score 7):

This headstone is in Latin. Your transcription is quite good, but the text includes several abbreviations, which I've filled in below with brackets:

> D[EO] O[PTIMO] M[AXIMO]
>
> MORTALIT[ATIS] SUAE MEMOR
> ANDREAS SEYLER
> REIP[UBLICAE] MEMMING[EN] SENAT[OR]
> ET
> PHARMACOP[OLA]
> BIPONT[I] NAT[US]
> MDCCVI DIE XXIV APR[ILIS]
> MONUMENT[UM] HOC SEPULCRALE
> PARAVIT
> SIBI POSTERISQUE SUIS
> MDCCLXXII

Here's a literal translation:

> To God, most good, most great
>
> Mindful of his mortality, Andreas Seyler, a senator of the republic of Memmingen and a pharmacist, born at Bipontum [=Zweibrücken] on April 24, 1706, prepared this funerary monument for himself and for his descendents, in 1772.

Comment: Is the year at the end just a signature of the year itself, or is it to be understood as part of the phrase, "in 1772", as you state? Is there a clue in the writing that tell us which is the case?